# Object physics with collision detection in AR

Tags: three.js, aframe, physics-engine, ar.js, ammo.js

Interested in the issue of handling collisions in AR (AR.js with aframe). As I understand it, I need to connect a physics engine to the scene. There are many solutions for VR, for example https://boytchev.github.io/Physijs/, but I can't find something similar for AR. Is there something similar for AR (with AFrame)? Is it even possible to do something like this in AR?

Need to be able to collide several objects and get information about which vertices / polygons this happened. I also found ammo.js, but it looks like it can only work with VR.

Comment: if you have any example in `a-frame` working it VR, it should work in arjs as well. Did you try any VR example in arjs?

Comment: Yes, I have an example with physics in the vr-scene (using https://github.com/c-frame/physx), but in the ar-scene the behavior of the models is inadequate (you can see how the models move behind the camera after the fall, although they should remain lying on the red floor, check my example video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/duHoHlx3-o0). Plus, as I understand it, there is no analogue of orbitControls for AR, I found only a gesture-handler (https://github.com/fcor/arjs-gestures) with limited functionality.

Comment: I'll try making an example this week